# Using InstallUtil to install service in its own process

Tags: c#, .net, service, installation

I have succesfully installed my service using InstallUtil, but I would like my service to run in its own process instead of in svchost.   If I was doing this via say winmgmts, I could just pass OWN_PROCESS to it ([see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198763.aspx)).  How can I do this using a System.Configuration.Install.Installer?

My current code:

```
  [RunInstaller(true)]
  public partial class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
  {
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;
    private ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller;

    public MyServiceInstaller ()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
      serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

      processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

      serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;
      serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService";

      Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
      Installers.Add(processInstaller);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to have to assume that this is not possible with this method.  I long ago simply used another method (sc.exe) to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

Don't all Windows services have to run inside an svchost?

When you install your service its just a registry key to the service, when windows starts up it scans these entries and loads the required processes inside service hosts. these then monitor the service and provide the facilities such as auto. restarte tc.

If you want your service to run as a normal exe then I understand you loose the facilities offered by the windows service model.

Comment: No. Not all services have to run in svchost.

Comment: I just did it using sc.exe

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true

notice the type= own parameter, "The service runs in its own process. It does not share an executable file with other services. This is the default."